# cant send message to specific user. connection.on not being reached

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I cant seem to reach the client from the hub.  All I have is a .on on the client side and I am just trying to reach a break point but its never being reached.  I have others on the client side I can reach without issue. I am not receiving any errors and not seeing any script issues in the dev tools console. All I want to do is fire off an action to a specific user. I have tried using both .Client and .User with the same result

On my client I have

```js
connection.on("SendRequest", function (requestmessage) {

    var whatever = requestmessage;
});
```

then in the hub

```cs
public async Task RequestPrivateChat(string UserListJS)
{
    var ConnectionID = "";

    MyUser user = new MyUser();
    string message = "This is my message";
    dynamic UserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(UserListJS);
    foreach (string item in UserList)
    {
        //I get the user okay then use the user.id below
        user = _db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == item).FirstOrDefault();
        //I get the connection ID okay
        ConnectionID = _connections.GetConnections(item).First();

        //Both of these are reached but the client is never reached out to. Both Connection ID and user.Id are populated correctly
        await Clients.Client(ConnectionID).SendAsync("SendRequest", message);
        await Clients.User(user.Id.ToString()).SendAsync("SendRequest", message);
    }
}
```

This for sending messages to all clients works fine

Hub

```cs
await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", name, message);
```

Client

```js
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});
```

UPDATE
I have tried moving this outside of visual studio into IIS just in case this was and IDE issue with same result.  I also tried the following

```
await Clients.User("username").SendAsync("SendChatRequest", message);
```

and it still didn't work but oddly enough I realized when I first go to the hub

```
connection.on("SendRequest", function (requestmessage)
```

is being hit without ever being called.  I have confirmed there are only 2 references to send request, one in the hub and one on the client.  I am sure there is something I am missing.

Comment: Does it work for ```await Clients.Client.All.SendAsync("SendRequest", message);```?

Comment: no, clients.client requires a connection ID so it has to be Clients.Client(string connectionId)......

Comment: sorry, what I meant was ```await this.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendRequest", message);```

Comment: Yes, that one worked

Comment: so it seems like only when I am trying to send to a particular user, either by user id or connection id

Comment: what you can do it is to add the connection to a group, and call the message to ```sendToGroupAsync```

Comment: and why did you do ```var ConnectionID = "";``` ? you are using latter the null connection id. You should do this: ```await Clients.Client(this.Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("SendRequest", message);```

Comment: so I am new to singalr but I assumed that this.Context.ConnectionID would give me the connection ID of the caller, so I am searching for the connection ID and setting it here
```
_connections.GetConnections(item).First();
```

Comment: So adding the users to the group then sending works,  I am still confused as to why I have to do this but it meets another goal which is sending to a selected group of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `await this.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendRequest", message);` works, you not passing correctly the connectionId to target the user.

What I suggest is:

- Get the connection Id from the context like:

```cs
await Clients.Client(this.Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("SendRequest", message);
```

- Get the connection Id from the caller:

```cs
await Clients.Caller(this.Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("SendRequest", message);
```

- Add the client to specific group and call the method for the group (assuming you added the connection in to a group):

```cs
await Clients.Group("GroupName").SendAsync("SendRequest", message);
```

Comment: I am keeping a hash set mapping of users to connection. On the front end I am selecting a user name or names, Based on this selection(s) I get the first connection ID for the user name using _connections.GetConnections(item).First(); which grabs the connection from the hash set.  I am not sure how context would know which user name(s)/Connections I am selecting from the front end.  so maybe there is still something I am missing.

Comment: I did verify that the connectionID is being set properly though so its not an issues with the connectionID. I also tried this based on the username shown above which I verified is also being set properly but this fails as well

Comment: The context knows who is calling your method.

Comment: but I am calling my method to send a message to connection IDs other than mine.

Comment: As I said, for this specific task, the groups would be a better approach to your problem.

Comment: @Grayson good luck then! Don't forget to share when you will find a solution!

Comment: so I deleted  my last comment before I saw your response because I think I changed my mind.  I think the group didn't solve my original issue but it does allow for other functionality that I am planning in the future.  Its hard to know how text is being received so I hope I didnt sound unappreciative. This really was a big help. If I do decide to revisit this though I will be sure to post what I found.